# Симплекс Метод C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Заранее спасибо за помощь. Не работает программа для Симплекс Метода.
Сам visual studio выдает ошибку с " Ошибка  CS1501  Ни одна из перегрузок метода "this" не принимает 2 аргументов.Строка 137"
Github:https://github.com/Nikolinc/Simplex-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int col; int r = 0;
        int row; int c = 0;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable basis = new DataTable();
       

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            table();
            initialization();
        }

        private void table()
        {
           col = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

           row = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

            dt.Columns.Add("Basis");
            for (int i=1;i <col+row+1; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add("X"+Convert.ToString(i));
            }
            dt.Columns.Add("Solving");

            dt.Rows.Add("F");
            for (int i = col+1; i< col + row + 1; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add("X"+Convert.ToString(i));
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
        private void initialization()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <row+1; i++)
            {                
                for (int j = 0; j < col + row +1; j++)
                {
               
                    if(j > col)
                    {
                     if ((i != 0)& (i == j - col))
                     {
                           

                       dt.Rows[i][j] = "1";
                            
                            
                     }
                        else
                        {
                            dt.Rows[i][j] = "0";
                        }
                    }                                        


                }
            }  
        }
         private void BasisTable()
        {
           col = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

           row = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

            basis.Columns.Add("Basis");
            for (int i=1;i <col+row+1; i++)
            {
                basis.Columns.Add("X"+Convert.ToString(i));
            }
            basis.Columns.Add("Solving");

            basis.Rows.Add("F");
            basis.Rows.Add("X"+Convert.ToString(r));
            for (int i = col+2; i< col + row+2; i++)
            {
                basis.Rows.Add("X"+Convert.ToString(i));
            }

            

        }



        private void Solvig(int max = int.MinValue, int min=int.MaxValue)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < row + 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < col + row + 1; j++)
                {
                    if ((j < col)&(i == 0))
                    {
                        if (Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][j])) > max)
                        {
                            max = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][j]);
                            c = i;
                        }
                    }
                    if(i == (row + 2))
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][j]) < min) 
                        {
                            min = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][j]);
                            r = j;                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < row+1; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j <  col + row+2; j++)
                {
                  basis.Rows[i,j]  = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][j]) * Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[c][r])) - Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][r])* Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[c][j])/ Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[c][r]));



                }
            }
          
          
        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BasisTable();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = basis;
            Solvig();
            
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dt.Clear();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Поменяйте `basis.Rows[i, j]` на `basis.Rows[i][j]`. Ошибки в скобках не было, но лучше конечно сократить эту строчку и сделать её более читабельной.

Comment: Спасибо большое, заработало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменял `basis.Rows[i, j]` на `basis.Rows[i][j]`. Подсказал в комментарии [@Павел Ериков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1258231/%d0%a1%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4-c/1331528#comment2211388_1258231).